# Visual Studio Express 2012 Web debug randomly not refreshing browser cache with changes

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Been using Visual Studio Express 2012 Web for a few weeks now learning JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS for a web based application. As a .NET developer its great to have the familiarity of VS (although better JS/HTML intellisense would be nice) and my progress is good, however there is an annoying VS quirk during debugging that I can't resolve. Occasionally VS (or perhaps more specifically IE10) will stop recognizing any code changes and run the previous version of the code. This is annoying but I can get around it by hitting an extra F5 when IE10 launches but it shouldn't be needed. I assume the file cache for IIS express is not being refreshed when the source is updated but I could be wrong. After a while of experiencing this problem I have not been able to pick up a pattern to understand what usage pattern causes the problem.

Has anyone else seen this? Any fixes? Searching the net draws a blank.

I use VS web site project types and have a vanilla installation of VS 2012 express (uses IIS express) on Windows 8 and debugging with IE10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has any web developer using visual studio web found a way around this? I found Chrome to be more reliable at ensuring the cache is refreshed when the code changes however with the IE & VS integration its easier to develop with IE.

This must be a common problem? I have tried IIS Express as well and the same issue (figures as I'm sure its a problem with the browser cache). Typically the problem occurs when running IE for the first time, and if there is a bug in my Javascript code that breaks the execution before the screen is painted its quite a pain as its not as easy to clear the cache manually. The only workaround I have is use F12 and 'clear browser cache for this domain' then F5 to refresh. Workable but annoying.

Any tips to resolve this would be appreciated

Comment: So I tried to update to IE11 via Windows 8.1 to see if this problem goes away. If anything it is now worse! IE11 does not have a "Always Refresh From Server" option and the only way to get this to work is to tell the browser to always reload web pages (via internet options - so a pain to always set). I can't get any of the META tags in the HTML to work but I have tracked the problem further that it is the included or loaded files from JavaScript that are problems and are never reloaded. I don't understand why IE doesn't check the timestamp is different on the include file and not use the cache

Comment: OK, got this to work. The problem is that IE won't check timestamps for files loaded within javascript when the automatic page caching option in IE is used (the default). To make this work, use the meta tag in the HTML being loaded to force a refresh, or in my case where I'm loading SVG files as objects in javascript, I extended the object type information to include the metadata (eg. "image/svg+xml;cache-control: no-cache; pragma: no-cache; max-age=0"). 
I hope this helps others.

Comment: Even better is to append a random query string to the end of the file being loaded. This forces the browser to load a new copy, and you can also insert condition checks in the code so that when running in debug mode the code appends the random query string but when running normally the random append isn't made so you get the benefits of local caching. Even sometimes this doesn't work, especially when running the application for the first time, so open F12 developer tools and select network-always get files from the server and clear the cache, then hit F5 to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function (e)
{
  if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY)
  {
    window.applicationCache.swapCache();
    if (confirm('A new version of this site is available. Load it?'))
     window.location.reload();
  }
}, false);
```

I found this solution somwhere in the Net. Sorry, but I don't remember the author. It works for me when I debug Web App with JavaScript in Visual Studio 2012 using IE.
Please, stop cursing Microsoft. We all use their pruducts, be fair.
I don't work at Microsoft but I would be unhappy without its products. I think all of us would.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I will try out your code to see if it works (problem is somewhat intermittent). Have updated to Win8.1 / RTM IE11 and the problem is less regular. I have nailed it down to loading files within the original page, sometimes it doesn't get the cache correct. What does work is to append a random parameter to the URL which forces a reload, although you want to remove it for production pages.

           iFrame.setAttribute("src", "dashboard.html?xx=" + Math.random());

Also, BTW I was not cursing Microsoft, I make my living within the Microsoft ecosystem and I think VS is great!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Chrome myself, but still experienced the same problem. In the end I settled on the solution of completely turning caching OFF on my local WebServer - being VS's IIS Express -. This can be done by adding a `UseMaxAge` of `0` to the `web.config`. As follows:

```
XML
<configuration>
  ...
    <system.webServer>
      ...
      <staticContent>
        ...
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="0.00:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Notes

- This works in regular/full IIS as well.
- Be sure **NOT** to deploy this setting to PRODUCTION. Use a production specific `web.config` there to allow end users to harness some caching :). Otherwise this could be a performance killer.
- Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> instead of just <kbd>F5</kbd> SHOULD also refresh it, however that somehow did not work either Chrome v39.0.2171.71 m). I found out it DID work to directly open the cached Javascript URL in the same browser (!) tab, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on that and then return to the (HTML) page and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> there again.
- Another option that sometimes works is to restart IIS Express (Taskbar right click and choose 'Exit' from context menu). But that is also pretty cumbersome.. :)